# Add href link using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have in my code this

```
<span class="link-hello">HELLO</span>
```

How can I using Javascript add a href link to word HELLO ?

Comment: I tried but all results are how to create and <a> element using Javascript not how to add a href to element by class

Comment: A `<span>` can't have an `href` (Or at least, it won't work as a link if you add one) You will need an `<a>` if you want it to actually navigate somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

use `<a><a/>` tag instead of `<span></span>` tag

`<a href="your_link" class="link-hello">Hello</a>`

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible because this code is inside CMS systém in field which does not support a href tag... it support only span tag with class... thats why I am asking for help how can I achieve using JS to add a href